# How can I find vector elements that meet a condition of a 1:1000 length vector X, namely X>10?

Tags: matlab

The code is the following:

```
for i = 1:1000

        x1 = TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput([1:200],[25]);
        x2 = TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput([1:200],[26]);
        x3 = TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput([1:200],[27]);
        x4 = TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput([1:200],[28]);
        x5 = TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput([1:200],[29]);
        x6 = TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput([1:200],[30]);
        x7 = TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput([1:200],[31]);
        x8 = TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput([1:200],[32]);
        x9 = TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput([1:200],[33]);
        x10 = TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput([1:200],[34]);
        x11 = TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput([1:200],[35]);
        X = (x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+x11)/11;
        S(i) = X(X>10); 

end  

        plot(S);
```

And I get the following error:

```
Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.

Error in open83B_edited_3 (line 189)
  S(i) = X(X>10);
```

Could someone help in finding a way to avoid this error? Thank you.

Comment: What data type is `S`? That's where your problem is.  MATLAB thinks `S` is a 1D array when you are trying to assign a 2D array to each location of `S`.  Can you please show more code?... especially where you are declaring `S`?  Also, if you can provide more insight as to why you are doing `X(X > 10)` and what it's **supposed** to do, we can suggest alternatives to make it compatible with `S` if a 1D array is truly what you want. To start, perhaps make `S` a cell array.

Comment: Not your question, but replace the entire top portion of the loop with this:  `X = mean(TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput(1:200, 25:35), 2);`

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I want is S to be a vector which contains values (elements) bigger than 10. S is generated from X (which is an average of 11 vectors). The 11 vectors are: TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput([1:200],[25]...[35]), which are 200by25 to 200by35 vectors. I need to find and represent all values bigger than 10 within S.

Comment: @user3611812 - Make `S` a `cell` array.  Specify `S` to be `S = cell(1,1000);`, then replace `S(i) = X(X > 10);` to be `S{i} = X(X > 10);`.  This will account for each element to be uneven.  You can then access each vector by doing `S{1}, S{2}, ...`, etc.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, but I want to plot S (from 1 to 1000). So, if I make S as a cell array, I cannot plot it.

Comment: You will need to do as rayryeng suggests, because the number of elements you want to put into S(i) is variable i.e. potentially different on each iteration of loop i.  You could then write a loop through the cell array S to generate the plot as a post-process.